# Android Studio send from android to pc (windows) not working?

Tags: java, android

I want to send data form my phone to pc. when trying to do indicate this error:

```
I/System.out: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /192.168.8.102
  (port 7200): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out).
```

This is the Android studio code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText e1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt);
    }
    public void send_msg(View v)
    {
        String message = e1.getText().toString();
        BackgroundTask b1= new BackgroundTask();
        b1.execute(message);
    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    protected static class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>
    {
        Socket s ;
        PrintWriter writer;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... voids) {
            try {
                String message = voids[0];
                s = new Socket("192.168.8.102",7200);
                writer = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
                writer.write(message);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(e);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Netbeans code :

```
public class msgPass extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    static Socket s;
    static ServerSocket ss;
    static InputStreamReader isr;
    static BufferedReader br;
    static String message;
    /**
     * Creates new form msgPass
     */
    public msgPass() {
        initComponents();
    }

    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 406, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(72, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(88, 88, 88)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 255, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(185, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(msgPass.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(msgPass.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(msgPass.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(msgPass.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new msgPass().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        try {
            
            ss =  new ServerSocket(7200);
            
            while(true){
            s = ss.accept();
            if(s != null){
                System.out.println("done");
            }
            isr = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
            br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            message = br.readLine();
            
            System.out.println(message);
            jTextArea1.setText(message);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    public static javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: That is a network issue and nobody here can know why your smartphone cannot establish a tcp connection to your computer. It might be a firewall, the socket might not be open at all, a routing issue with your wifi or a typo in the IP address.

Comment: use `10.0.2.2` as your pc ip instead of  `192.168.8.102`

Comment: @Bahman why would that help?

Comment: @f1sh `10.0.2.2` is loop back from emulator to PC `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Comment: thaks all, code is work properly. error was my network settings.